# Copy and paste text on iOS Simulator using a paired PC to Mac

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

I've paired my Windows PC with a Macbook through Visual Studio. This way I can view and control the iOS Simulator on my PC, but there does not seem to be a way to copy and paste text.

I've tried to `CTRL` + `C` and `CTRL` + `V` but no luck. The `paste` option does not show either when long pressing a textbox in the simulator. It will show up only after copying inside the simulator, but that's not what I want.

Anybody can help me out here?